# Почему Exception не ловит IOException?

Tags: java, исключения

Почему следующий фрагмент кода не компилируется, показывая ошибку в строке //2 (просит добавить исключение в сигнатуру метода)? Ведь с помощью Exception можно поймать и обработать IOException. Если убрать первый catch с отловом IOException, все компилируется.

```
public static void test() {
        try {
            throw new IOException();//1
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("2");
            throw new IOException();//2
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("3");//3
        } finally {
            System.out.println("4");//4
        }
        System.out.println("5");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему следующий фрагмент кода не компилируется, показывая ошибку в
> строке //2

Потому что в строке `//2` у вас выбрасывается исключение, но не ловится, а ловить исключения можно только в блоке `try { ... }`, а в `catch` уже происходит попытка поймать исключение, если оно подходит

Поэтому, или нужно в методе указывать, что оно может кинуть исключение:

```
public static void test() throws <Исключение> {
```

Либо в `catch` добавить `try`/`catch`

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы ловите исключения в этом блоке:

```
try {
    throw new IOException();
}
```

а все остальные блоки `catch()` обрабатывают исключения, возникающие в блоке `try()`. Поэтому когда у вас происходит исключение `IOException` в блоке `catch()`, а исключение `IOException` проверяемое, то его в этом блоке никто не проверяет и компилятор ругается на ошибку.