# Помогите оптимизировать метод обработки exeption в Java

Tags: java

Помогите оптимизировать метод обработки исключений:

```
    public void myException() throws IllegalStateException, Exception, RuntimeException
    {
        System.out.println("Start");
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Step 1");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Catch IllegalArgumentException");
            throw new RuntimeException("Step 2");
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Catch RuntimeException");
            throw new RuntimeException("Step 3");
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Step finally");
            throw new RuntimeException("From finally");
        }
    }
```

Насколько я понимаю

1. Два раза бросаем RuntimeExeption, в последнем блоке catch и в finaly.
2. Избыточная конструкция try, catch с trow new и trows в сигнатуре метода.
3. ..

Comment: Из вопроса не ясно, что можно, а что нельзя менять. Тут много чего можно выбросить, а именно много кода, который не влияет никак на конечный результат. Не ясно часть ли это упрощения для того, чтоб задать вопрос и его все таки выбрасывать нельзя? Я говорю о бросании исключений в обработчиках. Они никак не влияют на функционал. Да и исключение в try фиксированное - все известно заранее. Потому нужно уточнить, что можно а что нельзя менять.

Comment: вы уже не поймаете RuntimeException, он вылезет наружу. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1263439/192901

Comment: @RomanKonoval менять можно все что не влияет на функционал, насколько я понимаю trow  exeption в обработчиках дублируется в сигнатуре метода.

Comment: Мой совет: работай в данном случай через условные `if-else`. Так, как ты сделал, никто не делает!

Comment: @ArturVartanyan, согласен, но задача была использовать Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если выбросить все что не влияет никак на видимый конечный результат, то получим:

```
public void myException() throws IllegalStateException, Exception, RuntimeException
{
    System.out.println("Start");
    System.out.println("Step 1");
    System.out.println("Catch IllegalArgumentException");
    System.out.println("Step finally");
    throw new RuntimeException("From finally");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

вот так?

```
import java.io.IOException;
//...
public void myException() throws IllegalStateException, IOException, RuntimeException
{
    System.out.println("Start");
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Step 1");
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Catch IllegalArgumentException");
        throw new RuntimeException("Step 2");
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Catch RuntimeException");
        throw new RuntimeException("Step 3");
    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("Step finally");
    }
}
```

Comment: да это похоже на правду, почему был добавлен IOException?

Comment: RuntimeException и IOException являются прямыми наследниками Exception,  в вашем случае  это - дублирование, оба эти исключения можно спокойно заменить на Exception /**public void myException() throws IllegalStateException, Exception...  */и далее по коду тоже.